# Programatically rendering Blaze template loses context/scope

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

Let's say I have defined the following template and helpers:

```
var template = Template.fromString('{{#each people}}{{name}} {{/each}}');
var helpers = {
  people: function() {
    return [
      {name: 'Tim'},
      {name: 'Mary'},
      {name: 'John'}
    ];
  },
  fun: function(s) {
    return '[' + s + ']';
  }
};
```

(I'm using `numtel:template-from-string` to generate the template from a string.)

The following code works:

```
Blaze.toHTMLWithData(template, helpers); // returns "Tim Mary John "
```

And, this works too:

```
template = Template.fromString('{{fun "Test"}}');
Blaze.toHTMLWithData(template, helpers);  // returns "[Test]"
```

However, this does not work as expected. I would expect it to return `"[Tim] [Mary] [John] "`, but instead it produces an error:

```
var template = Template.fromString('{{#each people}}{{fun name}} {{/each}}');
Blaze.toHTMLWithData(template, helpers);
```

I get:

```
Uncaught Error: No such function: fun(…)
```

I basically just need the helpers and data to be passed through into all the child scopes and contexts that get evalutaed here.

I don't need to get it to work with `Blaze.toHTMLWithData`, I'm fine with a longer solution that recursively evaluates sections, etc.

I just need to get it to work. Any ideas?